# Javascript remove leading number label from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some strings that look like this:

```
1.     Some stuff
2.     some more stuff
...
26.    Even more stuff
```

What is a good way to remove the leading number labels on these strings in javascript?

(Each line is a separate string in a separate variable)

Thanks!

Comment: `str.replace(/\d+\./g,'')` are each line in a seperate string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/^\d+\.\s*/, '');
```

Comment: If you are using the variable `str` in the expression then it already exists, so don't declare it again.

Comment: @Guffa I think I had one of the OP's strings there originally, but it invoked the horizontal scrollbar of the code block so I removed it, and forgot about the LHS.

Answer (score 4):

```
var s = "26.    Even more stuff";

s.replace(/^[0-9]+/g, '')
```

Comment: This Chunk of code is work for me. i have used it as my string is "15501268622080Updated Details.docx" and it gives me output like "Updated Details.docx".  thank you so much @gary

Comment: That's the only one that worked well in my case, removing leading numbers and leaving the rest intact!

Answer (score 2):

```
"123. some text".match(/^[0-9]+\.\s+(.*)$/)[1] // "some text"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just this line:

```
s = "26.    Even more stuff";
s = s.replace(/^[^.]+\./, "")
```

#### OUTPUT

```
    Even more stuff
```

Comment: The `replace` method doesn't change the string that you call it on, you have to do something with the result or the code will accomplish nothing.

Comment: @Guffa: Agreed, I didn't mean to provide full JS code. Just wanted to provide regex code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression that matches the beginning of the string, any number of digits, the period and the white space after it:

```
s = s.replace(/^\d+\.\s+/, '');
```

This will leave the string unchanged if it would happen to look differently.

Comment: If you really want to match the period exclusively, you'll need to escape it.

Comment: @alex: I escaped it, but I typed too few spaces in front of the code to make it a code block.

Answer (score 0):

> str = "2.     some more stuff";
>
> str = str.replace(/[0-9]+.\s+/, "");

Comment: The `replace` method doesn't change the string that you call it on, you have to do something with the result or the code will accomplish nothing.